# Spread Array of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a `react-redux` application, and I have a reducer named `dataReducer` that has a default state like this:

```
const defaultState = {
  isLoading: false,
  data: [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'abc',
    elements: [{ color: 'red', id: 1}],
  }],
};
```

One of the reducers adds elements to `data` in the `defaultState`. I need to test this reducer by passing the payload and then validating the new state. I want to use the spread operator to build the new state from the old `defaultState`, but I am having some trouble achieving it. I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
const newElement = {
  colour: 'blue',
  id: 1
};

const newState = [
  {
    ...defaultState.data[0],
    elements: [{
      ...defaultState.data[0].elements,
      ...newElement,
    }]
  }
];

expect(dataReducer(defaultState, action)).toEqual(newState); // returns false
```

It would be great if I could somehow avoid using array index (`defaultState.data[0]`) as there might be multiple objects in the `defaultState` array in the real application, though for the purpose of testing, I am keeping just one object to keep things simple.

Comment: The new entry goes in `state.data[0].elements`? Not `state.data`?

Comment: `newElement` has the same structure than `state.data[0].elements` elements, so it seems to belong to it. Do you want to mix `state.data` elements with different model?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The new entry goes in `elements` of that object in the `data` array that has the same `id` as that object. So the `id` of the object and the `newElement` should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding to the end, you spread out the other aspects of state in the new state object, then override `data` with the current contents of it followed by the new entry:

```
const newState = {               // New state is an object, not an aray
  ...defaultState,               // Get everything from defaultState
  data: [                        // Replace `data` array with a new array
    {
      ...defaultState.data[0],   // with the first item's contents
      elements: [                // updating its `elements` array
        ...defaultState.data[0].elements,
        newElement
      ]
    },
    ...defaultState.data.slice(1) // include any after the first (none in your example)
  ]
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const defaultState = {
  isLoading: false,
  data: [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'abc',
    elements: [{ color: 'red', id: 1}],
  }],
};

const newElement = {
  colour: 'blue',
  id: 1
};

const newState = {               // New state is an object, not an aray
  ...defaultState,               // Get everything from defaultState
  data: [                        // Replace `data` array with a new array
    {
      ...defaultState.data[0],   // with the first item's contents
      elements: [                // updating its `elements` array
        ...defaultState.data[0].elements,
        newElement
      ]
    },
    ...defaultState.data.slice(1) // include any after the first (none in your example)
  ]
};

console.log(newState);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

There's no getting around specifying the entry in `data` that you want (e.g., `data[0]`).

---

In a comment you've asked how to handle this:

> Let's say `data` (present inside `defaultState`) has multiple objects entries in it. First object has `id` of 1, second one has `id` of 2. Now the `newElement` to be added has an `id` of 2. So the `newElement` should get added to the second object. Where in second object? Inside the elements property of the second object. The addition should not over-write existing entries in the elements array.

You'll need to find the index of the entry in `data`:

```
const index = defaultState.data.findIndex(({id}) => id === newElement.id);
```

I'm going to assume you know that will always find something (so it won't return `-1`). To then apply that `index` to the code above, you'd do this:

```
const newState = {                        // New state is an object, not an aray
  ...defaultState,                        // Get everything from defaultState
  data: [                                 // Replace `data` array with a new array
    ...defaultState.data.slice(0, index), // Include all entries prior to the one we're modifying
    {
      ...defaultState.data[index],        // Include the entry we're modifying...
      elements: [                         // ...updating its `elements` array
        ...defaultState.data[index].elements,
        newElement
      ]
    },
    ...defaultState.data.slice(index + 1) // include any after the one we're updating
  ]
};
```

The only real change there is adding the `...defaultState.data.slice(0, index)` at the beginning of the new `data`, and using `index` instead of `0`.

Live Example:

```js
const defaultState = {
  isLoading: false,
  data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: 'abc',
        elements: [{ color: 'red', id: 1}],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: 'def',
        elements: [{ color: 'green', id: 2}],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        label: 'ghi',
        elements: [{ color: 'yellow', id: 3}],
      }
  ],
};

const newElement = {
  colour: 'blue',
  id: 2
};

const index = defaultState.data.findIndex(({id}) => id === newElement.id);

const newState = {                        // New state is an object, not an aray
  ...defaultState,                        // Get everything from defaultState
  data: [                                 // Replace `data` array with a new array
    ...defaultState.data.slice(0, index), // Include all entries prior to the one we're modifying
    {
      ...defaultState.data[index],        // Include the entry we're modifying...
      elements: [                         // ...updating its `elements` array
        ...defaultState.data[index].elements,
        newElement
      ]
    },
    ...defaultState.data.slice(index + 1) // include any after the one we're updating
  ]
};

console.log(newState);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: If I have multiple objects in the `data` array, is there no way to 'spread' all the existing object entries in `data` before adding the last object entry at the end?

Comment: @maverick - Yes, but I thought you wanted to update the `elements` property of the first object in `data`?

Comment: The `newElement` to be added will actually get added in the `elements` array if the `id` of the `newElement` matches the `id` of any of the objects in `data` array.

Comment: @maverick - I'm afraid I can't figure out what you're saying there. Do you mean it'll get added to the first entry in `data` that has any entry in `elements` with a matching `id`?

Comment: Let's say `data` (present inside `defaultState`) has multiple objects entries in it. First object has `id` of 1, second one has `id` of 2. Now the `newElement` to be added has an `id` of 2. So the `newElement` should get added to the second object. Where in second object? Inside the `elements` property of the second object. The addition should not over-write existing entries in the `elements` array.

Comment: @maverick - I've added to the answer.